# How do I get all of the editting abilities back?

Tags: 3d-view

I'm working in blender 2.8 and clicked render image to see what my donut looked like (I'm following blender guru's donut tutorial) and once I exited the render image view I lost all tool bars. How do I get them back?

[image: this is what my screen looks like, there is no property bar or scene bar or tabs that line the top]

Comment: Select your mesh and press tab on your keyboard

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to have the full screen mode, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Spacebar</kbd> again.

Comment: or Ctrl+Alt+Space

Comment: Yes except here we still see his tools